# Subroutine Name Fortran Name

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a variable that stores the name of of a subroutine. Is there a way I can call the subroutine by using "call [variable]".

I have several subroutine (example names: X_1, X_2, X_3, etc), and the user provides the number (1, 2, 3, etc), and then the code is supposed to operate subroutine associated with the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible automatically by the compiler. You must prepare a table which stores the numbers or names according which they should be selected and then call the right subroutine.

After that you can choose the right function using a select case construct.

```
select case (n)
  case (1)
    call subroutine_1
  case (2)
    call subroutine_2
end select
```

or

```
select case (name)
  case ("subroutine_1")
    call subroutine_1
  case ("subroutine_2")
    call subroutine_2
end select
```

You can also use a table with function pointers. The amount of work required will be similar.